# Cargar datos cuando tenga la variable cargada | Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular5

estoy consumiendo un servicio de una API en Node.JS y MongoDB esta es la consulta.

```
this._productService.getProductById(productId).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.product = response['product'];
  },
  error => {
    console.log('Error');
  }
);
```

Cuando se completa la petición se guarda el valor del resultado en la variable product, pero la web renderizar antes el contenido de esa variable antes de que el servicio introduzca los datos que devuelve el backend, como puede decirle que espere que el servicio devuelva los datos y después muestre los datos en el html? yo en el HTML lo tengo así.

```
{{product.name}}
```

Pero me da el siguiente error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProductComponent.html:6)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21873)
at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:22077)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21874)
at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
```

Y el ngOnInit() lo tengo así.

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.url = GLOBAL.url;
this.categoryId = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("category");
this.productId = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("product");
this.getProductById(this.productId);
```

}

Comment: Para evitar el error puedes hacer un ngIf y consultar que product no sea nulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular [tiene una sintaxis](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) que permite solucionar este error de un modo sencillo:

```
{{product?.name}}
```

Esto es lo mismo que en simple Javascript sería

```
{{product == null ? '' : product.name}}
```

Pero tiene la ventaja de que se puede enlazar fácilmente:

```
{{a?.b?.c}} // muestra c si tanto a como b no son null o undefined
```

Comment: Gracias ya lo he solucionado tal y como me lo has indicado, un saludo.